# Access a USB device (not a memory stick) in a Docker container from a macOS host

Tags: docker, usb, containers

Is it possible to access a USB device (which is not a memory stick) in a Docker container?

I've come across the `--—privileged` and `--device` options which I guess would work if I had a Linux host, but they don't seem to work in macOS where USB devices don't show up in `/dev`.

Comment: I found [this blog post](http://gw.tnode.com/docker/docker-machine-with-usb-support-on-windows-macos/) very useful

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `docker-machine` + VirtualBox is the way to go. I documented the steps I took in the blog post *[How to use a USB device in a Docker container on Mac](http://milad.ai/docker/2018/05/06/access-usb-devices-in-container-in-mac.html)*.

Comment: I read the post you mentioned but my problem is that I want to use the device in my local docker not inside the docker of the virtual machine.

Comment: I don't think there's a local docker or docker of the virtual machine. You can have different docker providers in the background for your docker and all we're doing is switching to a different provider, i.e. VirtualBox instead of HyperVisor. I do agree that it's hacky but seems to work